# How to enable guest checkout for particular store in multi-store site in magento?

Tags: magento-1.8

I have two stores in my Magento site. I want to enable guest checkout for one store and the other store should not have guest checkout. How can I do this in Magento 1.8 ?

Any Help Appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

By default Magento only allows you to set your entire site to either allow or disallow guest checkout. This option is in System > Configuration > Sales > Checkout. This option for some reason is hidden on store view level even though the code below supports it. Luckily this is easy to change.

Within **/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Helper/Data.php** there is the **isAllowedGuestCheckout()** function.

```
/**
 * Check is allowed Guest Checkout
 * Use config settings and observer
 *
 * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Quote $quote
 * @param int|Mage_Core_Model_Store $store
 * @return bool
 */
public function isAllowedGuestCheckout(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote $quote, $store = null)
{
    if ($store === null) {
        $store = $quote->getStoreId();
    }
    $guestCheckout = Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(self::XML_PATH_GUEST_CHECKOUT, $store);

    if ($guestCheckout == true) {
        $result = new Varien_Object();
        $result->setIsAllowed($guestCheckout);
        Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_allow_guest', array(
            'quote'  => $quote,
            'store'  => $store,
            'result' => $result
        ));

        $guestCheckout = $result->getIsAllowed();
    }

    return $guestCheckout;
}
```

You can see within this function that it is actually getting the configuration flag for the store.

```
    $guestCheckout = Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(self::XML_PATH_GUEST_CHECKOUT, $store);
```

So in theory if you open up **app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/system.xml** and change the  options to 1 for the various sections it should allow you to enable on a store level. The start of the file would look something like this:

*Obviously you shouldn't modify this core file and instead place this in your own xml file!*

```
<config>
    <sections>
        <checkout translate="label" module="checkout">
            <label>Checkout</label>
            <tab>sales</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>305</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <options translate="label">
                    <label>Checkout Options</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <onepage_checkout_enabled translate="label">
                            <label>Enable Onepage Checkout</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </onepage_checkout_enabled>
                        <guest_checkout translate="label">
                            <label>Allow Guest Checkout</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </guest_checkout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Default configuration allows Magento to handle both registered users AND guests. To disable guests for another store go to `System > Configuration > Sales > Checkout > Checkout Options`. As you can see there's an option to disable or enable guests. Don't do anything yet. Please note that this options has *"Store View"* scope.

Now change store scope scope (upper left corner, *Current Configuration Scope*) and choose store you want guest checkout disable for. Page will reload and suddenly there's a checkbox with label *Use Default*. Uncheck this checkbox for you scope and change *Allow Guest Checkout* to *No*. Save.

Please note that the value is also inherited to all the children scopes. You can in turn override child values as well by unchecking their *Use Default* checkboxes as well.

Comment: Seems to be that this is only available on the website level and not on the store level

Comment: Does it really matter? Since it's available on *Store View* level you can disable the functionality for all the views you have. Or you could create a new Website and assign your store there.

Comment: Very true, you could create a new website with a single store in it. Just wanted to point out that it would not work if you have on the website level. Not 100% sure if they are asking about multiple store or view.

Comment: Well, one can always disable guest checkout view by view.

Comment: @Pronto you can easily enable this option for store view level. The getStoreConfig supports it. See my response above.